# Div has inexplicably huge right margin?

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I have a sidebar div that for some reason has an absolutely massive right margin and I cannot figure out why this is happening. This screws up the floats for the rest of the stuff on my page and need your help to figure out why this is happening.

I've checked the rest of my CSS for any kind of conflicting CSS that might be assigning a huge margin but can't seem to find any.

I understand some of this is out of context but just bear with me.

#### The div

```
<div id="leftsidebar">
    <h2> Yesterday's Games </h2>
    <img src="images/dividerSmall.gif" />
    <div class="gamelist">
        **gamelist is populated by MySQL database**
    </div>
</div>
```

#### The CSS for any related divs

```
#leftsidebar {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 225px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.gamelist {
    height: auto;
    width: 225px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: -27px;
}
```

Comment: If you can make a miniature test case on jsfiddle or somewhere that has the problem, it would be much easier to help.

Comment: Do you have a picture, or a rough estimate in pixels of how big the right margin is? Either way, you might need to post more of the HTML, because this might be an issue with the parent of `leftsidebar`

Comment: Is this happening in all Browsers?

Comment: If you take at jsfiddle you will notice already that your .gamelist is hanging outside of the sidebar's width because of the set width on the .gamelist class, I added background colors to the css. http://jsfiddle.net/e8N5N/2/

Comment: @melee @Yonoran After looking at it in firefox, it appears that it is somehow inheriting the width of the parent, `#content`, which has a width of `1200px`. Which doesnt make any sense because I set the width in `#leftsidebar`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not use float in your css. Try using that i.e. `float:left`; in your `#leftsidebar` and `.gamelist`. Might help :)

Answer (score 2):

Well from looking at your CSS, `#leftsidebar` has an actual width of `235px` (225 width + 10 padding) and `.gamelist` has an actual width of `245px` (225 width + 20 padding). This is because padding is always accounted for in the total element width.

So if you take those two numbers and offset them, you will get a 20px overflow of `.gamelist`. Why? Because `.gamelist` is positioned 10 pixels to the right due to the padding on `#leftsidebar`. So the correct width for `.gamelist` should have been 205px (225 width - 20 padding).

See http://jsfiddle.net/e8N5N/3/ for an updated example.

Comment: You could also just add overflow: hidden; to .leftsidebar and be done with it.

Comment: all good points, and I updated my `leftsidebar` to completely contain my `gamelist`. However, the margin that I'm talking about is something close to 1000px which isn't really accounted for by this and isn't fixed by this.

Comment: @Tory Waterman any chance you could get a skeleton of your HTML and post it on the fiddle mentioned in this answer? It's a problem with the `#content` div it seems